# matching begin and pattern without end with tmLanguage

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to define a language using tmLanguage for syntax highlighting in vscode. I have the following rule.

```json
"sexp": {
  "name": "entity.sexp",
  "patterns": [
    {"include": "#list_of_sexp"},
    {"include": "#atom"}
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to have a comment rule that matches sexp prefixed with a ";"? I'm not sure what to put in "end".

```json
"comment": {
  "name": "comment.sexp",
  "begin": ";",
  "end": ??,
  "patterns": [{ "include": "#sexp" }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this with a positive lookahead regex in “end”.